# How to add Google Analytics on existing .Net MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, google-analytics

Assume, we already have an analytics account.

Working a .NET MVC app which is using Razor syntax. I tried to add the following line of codes into the .cshtml file. But I see, it's not working. Aready downloaded `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers` using NuGet console. And then in the code, if I type `@Analytic`..., the IDE is not suggesting any type of code.

```
@using Microsoft.Web.Helpers;


<div id="analytics">
 @Analytics.GetGoogleHtml("GoogleAnalyticID")
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong? or missing something?